# How to split odd number samples in an array?

Tags: python, split, chunks

I have an array of values with a length of y (y = 7267).
I am splitting the data based on x (x = 24) as shown below.
I miss some values here because 7267/24 gives 302, not 302.8. This is because I am taking integer values.
If I set `int` to `float` in the 3rd line, I get an error `TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.
How can I run the following code without losing any values in y? or maybe there is a better way of splitting the data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)?

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.rand(7267)
samples = len(y)
x = 24

trim = samples % x
subsequences = int(samples/x)
sequence_trimmed = y[:samples - trim]
sequence_trimmed.shape = (subsequences, time_steps, 1)
```

Comment: Give an example please

Comment: How does the edit look?

Comment: You can use the `//` operator to force integer division instead of casting it -- `samples // x`

Comment: that still gives 302. so basically using either  `int(samples/x)` or `samples//x` is the same, no?

Comment: How about `trim = round(samples / x)` - this gives you 303

Comment: That throws error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 7248 into shape (303,24,1)`

Comment: I have posted an answer

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
subsequences = samples // x
```

`//` is integer division so it'll return an integer exp.

```
var // x + var % x = var / x
```

Answer (score 2):

The modulo operation (`%`) is only defined for integers, that's why you cannot change it to float.
An array also takes only (integer,integer) shapes.
If I understand you correctly and you want to have an array that is shaped `(x, z)` for some `z` and that will definitely take all your data, how about introducing some zeros?
So

```
z=samples//x+1
array=np.zeros(x*z)
array[:samples]=y
np.reshape(array,(x,z))
```

might do the trick?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. However, I get  7272 instead of 7267 in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [28]: import numpy as np
    ...:
    ...: y = list(range(7267))
    ...: samples = len(y)
    ...: x = 24
    ...:
    ...: trim = round(samples / x)
    ...: subsequences = int(samples/x)
    ...: sequence_trimmed = y[:samples - trim]
    ...:
```

Comment: You miss the last line of the code. It throws this error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 6964 into shape (302,24,1)`

Comment: I'm using list not numpy array

Comment: But I have an array.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
import numpy as np

y = np.random.rand(7267)
samples = len(y)
x = 24

trim = samples % x
subsequences = samples//x
sequence_trimmed = y[:samples - trim]
sequence_trimmed.shape = (subsequences, x)
```